# java.lang.NullPointerException for Object instantiateItem in ViewPager use in fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

```
    class PagesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
     {
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //Return total pages, here one for each data item
        return pageData.length;}

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    //Create the given page (indicated by position)
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
   View page = null;
   page = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page,null,false);
   ((TextView)page.findViewById (R.id.textMessage)).setText(pageData[position]);
        //Add the page to the front of the queue
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(page, 0);
        return page;
    }
```

Error:

```
1-16 18:41:34.354 24761-24761/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 18:41:34.354 24761-24761/? E/Android 
Runtimejava.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 18:41:34.354 24761-24761/? E/AndroidRuntime: atOnlytext $ MyPagesAdapter.instantiateItem
11-16 18:41:34.354 24761-24761/? E/AndroidRuntime:at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
11-16 18:41:34.354 24761-24761/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1020)
```

Comment: Organize your code and debug clearly please ;)

Comment: obviously possible causes: 1. inflater is null 2. page.findViewById(...) returns null 3. pageData is null ... also overriding `instantiateItem` in `FragmentPagerAdapter` derived class is totally wrong

Comment: FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdpter

Answer (score -1):

```
Maybe :


   @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
   View page = null;
   page = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page,container,false);
   ((TextView)page.findViewById (R.id.textMessage)).setText(pageData[position]);
        //Add the page to the front of the queue
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(page, position);
        return page;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [programming by permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation) ...  please explain how changing `addView(page, 0)` to  `addView(page, position)` would help with this NPE?

Comment: No .it inflater.inflate(R.layout.page,null ,false) to inflater.inflate(R.layout.page,container,false)

Comment: doesn't matter ... this parameter of `inflate` **can** be null ... while it is better to not use null there it will not cause NPE ...

Comment: yeah ... just take a look at LayoutInflater docs or source ... the key part of docs is **Optional** near description of `root` parameter ...